# Using github and posting my own play store app

Tags: github, google-play

I don't know whether this question should have come in this platform or not but I wanted to ask that let us say I made a github repository which was public. Now another person who has no relation with me downloaded the code, edited it and posted it in play store. I found out that this app which is in play store was my one of the github repositories with some edit. So should I issue a copyright or something or is it fine I should not do anything?

PS: This hasn't happened with me in real. I was just having fear of my repository being used by other but I guess they are so bad that no one would like to use them. Another thing is that pls don't comment that you should make your repositories private.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making you repo public you yourself are permitting others to use it. But to prevent misuse of your code and work there are open source licenses available that you can add to your public repo that will put some restrictions on its usage.

More info can be found here:

https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/licensing-a-repository

https://opensource.guide/legal/